# What is the name of function that is called when you use '%' in Emacs Evil normal mode?

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I'm looking to call this function programmatically, but can't figure out what function is actually called that moves point to matching bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is `evil-jump-item`.

You can easily find the answer yourself. When in evil normal node, just type `C-h k %`, and it will tell you what the function is and what it does. `C-h k` (which runs `describe-key`) will work in the same way for any key binding you want to know about.